# Altering MySQL table gives 1114 table is full

Tags: mysql

I am trying to alter one of my InnoDB tables. 
This is query:

```
ALTER TABLE `tf5h_assets`
   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `idx_asset_name` (`name`), ADD KEY `idx_lft_rgt` (`lft`,`rgt`), ADD KEY `idx_parent_id` (`parent_id`);
```

Error is:

```
#1114 - The table 'tf5h_assets' is full
```

I do not undesrtand how is it "full" when it's empty table i created from MySQL dump (structure, no data) file.

What's wierd is that i can alter it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `tf5h_assets`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `tf5h_assets`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `idx_asset_name` (`name`);

ALTER TABLE `tf5h_assets`
  ADD KEY `idx_lft_rgt` (`lft`,`rgt`);

ALTER TABLE `tf5h_assets`
  ADD KEY `idx_parent_id` (`parent_id`);
```

and it does not throw that error.
What am i doing wrong? 
This ALTER TABLE statements are from structure mysql dump file. Is there a way to split em like i did somehow when structure is exported so i dont have to do it manually?

I googles "table is full" error and this is what i did so far:

1) Checked for disk space - 80+ gigs of free space

2) Added to my.cnf :

```
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_file_format = barracuda
```

and rebooted mysql server and created fresh db.

EDIT:

I solved my problem but i have no idea how to solve it for databases that i will not be able to export from Joomla.

Thing is, phpmyadmin is separating table creation from key creation like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tf5h_assets` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key',
`parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set parent.',
`lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set lft.',
`rgt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set rgt.',
`level` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The cached level in the nested tree.',
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The unique name for the asset.\n',
`title` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The descriptive title for the asset.',
`rules` varchar(5120) NOT NULL COMMENT 'JSON encoded access control.'
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=382 ;
```

and than later on:

```
ALTER TABLE `tf5h_assets`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `idx_asset_name` (`name`), ADD KEY `idx_lft_rgt` (`lft`,`rgt`), ADD KEY `idx_parent_id` (`parent_id`);
```

and later on:

```
ALTER TABLE `tf5h_assets`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Primary Key',AUTO_INCREMENT=382;
```

I managed to get my database up and running by using Joomla's backup / restore component (It's Joomla site). I opened up MySQL dump that component created and this is what i found in there:

```
CREATE TABLE `#__assets` 
(`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Primary Key',   
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set parent.',   
  `lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set lft.',   
  `rgt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set rgt.',   
  `level` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The cached level in the nested tree.',   
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The unique name for the asset.\n',   
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The descriptive title for the asset.',  
   `rules` varchar(5120) NOT NULL COMMENT 'JSON encoded access control.',   
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),   
   UNIQUE KEY `idx_asset_name` (`name`),   
   KEY `idx_lft_rgt` (`lft`,`rgt`),   
   KEY `idx_parent_id` (`parent_id`) ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=382 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Whole process is executed in one run, and it works fine.

Now, i have luck it's Joomla database. But what will i do when database wont be Joomla's? I have no idea. Is there a way to change how phpmyadmin stores dump? Would terminal access to mysql create different mysql dump that would create database in one go instead of using "ALTER"?

Comment: I don't really care, but you wrote it so well that I had to upvote :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i still don't know what creates this problem except that it has something to do with how phpmyadmin exports databases and reimports them again.

And as i assumed in my original post that i will run into this problem with database that can not be exported trough Joomla component sooner or later, it happened...well...sooner.

Anyway, if you have console access to your mysql server you can deal with this by simply mysql dumping:
mysqldump -p NameOfDatabase > NameOfDumpFile.sql

Download dump file from server and you can import it trough phpmyadmin. It works like a charm. mysqldump creates databases in one query so there is no problem with assigning keys etc.